# How to un-fullscreen an application on your secondary monitor in 11.10

Tags: 11.10, panel, fullscreen

Nvidia twinview wasn't working for me very well so I uninstalled it and started using the nouveau driver, since then my dual monitors are working properly. With 11.10 the panel has changed. It appears on my main monitor only, along with the unity bar. When I have an application full screened the panel acts as the file menu, along with max, min, and close options.

However I'm noticing when I have something full screened on my secondary monitor (where there is no panel) I have no way of un-fullscreening it. The panel on the main monitor do not show any options when that window is selected. This is okay for some apps like my web browser that has these buttons in it anyway, but I fullscreened Banshee and now it's stuck there...

Any idea on how to un-fullscreen something in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to set up a keyboard shortcut to toggle maximization and/or fullscreen state.

Go to `Keyboard` settings, click on the `Shortcuts` tab and chose a new shortcut for that in the `Windows` section.

[image: maximization shortcut]